# Is there a function to create appointment with Outlook Web add-ins?

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I've created a form to select specific meeting hours. I call my add-ins from AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface extension point. My form is in a displayDialog. When the user confirm his choice (time, date, details, ...), the dialog close and all his information are copied in Outlook Appointment composer form.

Is there a function I can call to create appointment when the dialog box close and the add-ins call event.completed()? To avoid the need to confirm the appointment again.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean to avoid the need to confirm?  Since your addin is running on AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface, and you copied the information to the Outlook Appoinement composer form already, have you tried to save and close the form before calling event.completed? saveAsync and close are documented here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox.item?

Comment: I tried to `saveAsync ` and `close` the form, and calling `event.completed` after, but it only make a draft, and not an actual event. 

What I want, is when an user click on my confirm button in my form, that the event is create with email send to participant and room mailbox. I also get an information box saying that my add-ins is still working. Do I need to pass by EWS ?

Comment: No, there's no JS API to 'send' the item from the addin. Generally, we want to let the user send from the native UI. This is not what you asked, but would the on-send https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows be applicable in your scenario in that you trigger your dialog when user sends? REST/EWS is a possibility, but on desktop Outlook, what you set and save in the composer will take time to sync to the server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try something with the on-send! Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(moving previous comment to an answer)

No, there's no JS API to 'send' the item from the addin. Generally, we want to let the user send from the native UI.

This is not what you asked, but would the on-send learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/… be applicable in your scenario in that you trigger your dialog when user sends? REST/EWS is a possibility, but on desktop Outlook, what you set and save in the composer will take time to sync to the server.